# parse error for highlight in elasticsearch

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, aws-php-sdk

Using Elasticsearch for searching documents and its working fine if i query from Kibana,but if i use SDK for php and then add `highlight` it give me error like

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:211] [highlight] fields doesn't support values of type: VALUE_STRING"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:211] [highlight] fields doesn't support values of type: VALUE_STRING"},"status":400}`

**Kibana Query**

```
{
  "size": 20, 
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "tag": {
            "query": "Search_term_here",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "status": {
          "gte": 1,
          "lte": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"highlight": {
  "pre_tags": ["<strong>"],
  "post_tags": ["</strong>"], 
  "fields": {
    "tag":{}
  }
}
}
```

**SDK Query**

```
$params = [
    "index" => "catalog",
    "body"  => [
        "size" => 20, 
        "query" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    "match" => [
                        "tag" => [
                            "query" => $filter_name, 
                            "fuzziness" => "AUTO" 
                        ] 
                    ] 
                ], 
                "filter" => [
                    "range" => [
                        "status" => [
                            "gte" => 1, 
                            "lte" => 1 
                        ] 
                    ] 
                ] 
            ]
        ], 
        "highlight" => [
            "pre_tags" => ["<strong>"], 
            "post_tags" => ["</strong>"], 
            "fields" => [
                "tag" => [] 
            ] 
        ]
    ] 
];
```

Went through the documentation but didn't find any answer for this..
Any guess about this? Thanks